# VBA rounding function that stores its values for later use, getting an "Overflow" error message

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a rounding macro in VBA that loops through a few values from a worksheet, but I get "Overflow" error and not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
dim i as integer
dim x as double
dim RoundedAmounts (1 to 26) as Integer

for i = 1 to 26
     x = Range("I44").Offset(i,0).value
     RoundedAmounts(i)=Application.Worksheetfunction.Round(x,-4)

Next i
```

The code works for 2 values of x and i and then gives the "overflow" error message. Could you help solve this issue ? I am on a very beginner level so this might be obvious, but thanks in advance for any help, it is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of `x` when you get the error?  Why are you using `Application.WorksheetFunction.Round` instead of [the VBA `Round` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function)?  Are you aware that there is no memory saving when you use `Integer` in VBA (unlike in VB.net), so you should always use `Long` instead?

Comment: To second what @Chronocidal said about `Integer` vs. `Long` -- the only reason to ever use `Integer` is if you want to emphasize that the values stored in the variable are smallish and you *want* an overflow error if the values are too big since it would be an error condition that you don't want to pass silently.

Comment: hi thanks for the swift comment! I am using the worksheet function because i would like to round to negative decimal places, which is not possible as far as i know in the vba round function. The x value before the error is -52443.1530. Also thanks for the tip for using Long instead of integer i was not aware of that

Comment: my roundedamounts were set to integer which caused the issue, thanks for your help

Comment: @Chronocidal - `Round` and `WorksheetFunction.Round` do not work exactly the same way. `Round` uses bankers' rounding. Which is why the note in the documentation you shared specifically recommends using `WorksheetFunction.Round`.